# Storing Array of Struct in core Data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, struct

I'm learning how to use *PARSE* to store information of my user. Basically, I'm making a test app where the user can add a value (weight), date and comment. I upload this info to *parse.com* and I want to be able to retrieve all the info from *PARSE* and save it into core data each time the user logs in.

When I download it I create an struct for every element and then append it to an array. I was thinking in just save each element directly like this: [image]

This is my code to download and create the struct array:

```
func queryDownload (usuario : PFUser) {

        do {
            let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")
            query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
            let objects = try query.findObjects() as [PFObject]
            self.dataArray = objects.map { MyData(wheigt: $0["wValue"] as! Int, date: $0["date"] as! Date, info: $0["info"] as! String) }
            self.dataArrayOrdered = self.dataArray.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending})
            print(self.dataArrayOrdered)
        } catch {
            print("ERROR", error)
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to store it like this in coreData:

```
 let elements = dataArrayOrdered.count

        for i in 0...(elements - 1) {

        let newData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "", into: context)
        newData.setValue(dataArrayOrdered[i].wheigt, forKey: "wValue")
        newData.setValue(user, forKey: "user")
        newData.setValue(dataArrayOrdered[i].date, forKey: "date")
        newData.setValue(dataArrayOrdered[i].info, forKey: "comment")
        }
```

But I was told by my teacher that this is not a good idea and that I should consider other option for my CoreData data structure, but I can't come with any other idea.  What are your thoughts on this? I have been thinking that maybe the problem could be when I retrieve the info later on and try to create the array of structs, but I'm not sure, is there a better way to use coreData with this kind of data?

Comment: does your app require offline mode as well?

Comment: @Tushar Sharma Not really, it's just a test to see if we can download and upload the data